# Do any classical Sunni scholars say Islam is religion of peace?

Tags: sunni, islamic-philosophy

I have come across Islam as *religion of mercy and justice* in writing of people of knowledge:

> Islam is the religion of mercy and justice.
>   https://islamqa.info/en/13241

But haven't come across saying it's a *religion of peace*.  Do any classical sunni scholars say it's religion of peace?

Please provide Arabic quote.

Comment: Do you mean peace as in war/peace or as in inner peace?

Comment: Zakir naik often quotes islam means peace, peace as in peace/war

Comment: If he has said "Islam means peace", then he is wrong. If he said "Islam comes from the root word of peace", then he is right. In truth, peace is a hard to define concept. Islam certainly isn't pacifist like Buddhism (war is allowed with some conditions), but peace is always preferable.

Comment: Which period of time do you consider the scholars to be classical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of no place where a classical scholar calls Islam a "religion of peace".

Firstly because the term "religion of peace" is new, and has come into popular use after the September 11 Attacks, and before that had been used for Christianity in the 19th century. It wasn't really a term used in the time of the classical scholars.

> In 1996, the Organisation of The Islamic Conference agreed to call for "pragmatic and constructive steps to counter the negative propaganda against Islam; to remove and rectify misunderstandings; and to present the true image of **Islam: the religion of peace** and tolerance." (Wikipedia)
>
> Probably one of the first times there is a documented use of "religion of peace" to describe Islam.

Secondly because Islam is not a "religion of peace". It is as you said yourself better described as the religion of mercy and justice. And often times the path of mercy and justice is not the path of peace. e.g. Islam would allow or even encourage a Khalifa to take military action (Jihad) fighting against Hitler in WW2 even though it is not "peaceful".

> Fighting for self defense:
>
> Fight in the way of Allah those who fight you, but do not transgress. Indeed Allah does not like transgressors. (2:190)
>
> Fighting for victims of oppression:
>
> What is it with you that you do not fight in the way of Allah and the degraded men, women, and children, who say, ‘Our Lord, bring us out of this town whose people are wrongdoers, and appoint for us a guardian from You, and appoint for us a helper from You’?

Comment: > neither will Islam encourage organized military action "in the path of Allah"  (1) prophet said: “I have been sent just before the Hour with the sword, so that Allaah will be worshipped alone with no partner or associate. Narrated by Ahmad, 4869; Saheeh al-Jaami’, 2831.( 2)"I have been commanded to fight the people until they testify that there is no god but Allaah and that Muhammad is the Messenger of Allaah, and they establish regular prayer and pay zakaah, then if they do that, then they save their lives and property from me except for Islamic laws ." al-Bukhaari (24), Muslim (33).

Comment: (3)prophet said “I have been sent ahead of the Hour with the sword so that Allaah will be worshipped alone, and **my provision has been placed in the shade of my spear** and humiliation has been decreed for those who go against my command, and whoever imitates a people is one of them.”  Narrated by Ahmad, 4869; Saheeh al-Jaami’, 2831.

Comment: @Praveenladak . Did you read my whole paragraph? I said this is because of the lack of Khilafah. There is no Islamic military action without a Khilafah

Comment: @Praveenladak . "**So, effectively for the time being**"

Comment: I also addressed Islamic military action in point 2

Comment: Your answer confuses me, it gives the impression that Muslims are handicapped from Jihad and Qital (and even defensive war) in the absence of a Khilafat. If you are claiming that then you should probably cite evidence to support it. On the other hand [this hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/302) and the like might be relevant.